# Find $a\in\Bbb Z$ such that $a^3\equiv 3 \pmod{11}$ without Fermat or Euler.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> Find all $a$ integers such that $a^3\equiv 3 \pmod{11}$

I have this problem and I can't use Fermat or Euler theorems because we haven't seen them in class. I also have a solution that I don't understand. I would appreciate if someone explain to me the image solution and/or give me a different approach.

PD: On the image, 'o sea' is Spanish for 'that means'.

[image: A resolution of this problem I don't understand.]

Comment: Basically the answer says "let's try $a = 9$ and it works".

Comment: What about it do you not understand? You take each congruence class modulo $11$ and cube, reducing each time. $6^2\equiv 36\equiv 3\times 11+3\equiv 3\bmod 11$ and then $6^3\equiv 3\times 6\equiv 18\equiv 11\times 1+7\equiv 7\bmod 11$, so $6^3\equiv 7\bmod 11$. Keep going until you reach an $a$ such that $a^3\equiv 3\bmod 11$.

Comment: The values in the row containing $a\equiv 3$ is incorrect, btw.

Comment: It's just trial and error...since $11$ is so small, it doesn't take long.  Actually, they could have stopped with $2$ since $2^3\equiv 8\equiv -3\pmod {11}\implies (-2)^3\equiv 3\pmod {11}$ and, of course, $-2\equiv 9 \pmod {11}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is just working out $a^3\pmod{11}$ for each integer $n=0,1,\ldots,10$, finding which ones work. In each case they have worked it out by first calculating $a^2$, then reducing mod $11$, then multiplying the result by $a$ and reducing again.

Once you know that $a=9$ is the only solution in $0,\ldots,10$, then the general solution is $a\equiv 9\pmod{11}$. This is because if $a\equiv b$ then $a^3\equiv b^3$, so $a$ works if and only if $b$ does, and we can always choose $b$ to be in $0,\ldots,10$.

Answer (score 1):

It is shorter to show that
$$(-2)^3\equiv 3 \mod 11$$
and write the solution as $$a=-2+11k;\;\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$$